# ios application loader sign in hangs

Tags: ios

I'm using the new app-specific password to sign into application loader on a mac.  After I enter the password, it hangs on 'signing in to app store connect' forever.
Maybe this is a forced upgrade?  I'm using xcode 10.1, mac version is 10.13.6.  This is a mac build server for xamarin

Answer (score 0):

ok a restart of xcode did the trick.  as always a terrible experience